# Can Someone Help Me Make A Script that When you click a TextButton It runs the script?

Tags: lua, roblox

I wanted to make a Gui that when you press a TextButton to size your BodyWidth, BodyDepth, Head and BodyHeight and also change your walkspeed nad jumpower. I wanted it to understand when you clicked the button and run the script but I can't do it alone.
Here is the script:

```lua
--The error is here
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(Player)
    --Maybe here too
    Player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(Character)

        local Humanoid = Character.Humanoid

        Humanoid.BodyDepthScale.Value = 10
        Humanoid.BodyHeightScale.Value = 10
        Humanoid.BodyWidthScale.Value = 10
        Humanoid.HeadScale.Value = 10.5
        Humanoid.WalkSpeed =  70
        Humanoid.JumpPower = 0
    end)
end)
end)
```

I tried to make an if condition But I still couldn't do the script.

Comment: If Someone Can Help They Really Made My Day

Answer (score 0):

First add a LocalScript to the button, and type:

```
 local LocalPlayer = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer
local char = LocalPlayer.Character
local Humanoid = char:WaitForChild("Humanoid")

function Click ()
    Humanoid.WalkSpeed =  70
    Humanoid.JumpPower = 0
    -- scale the meshes right here like char.Head.Size = Vector3.new(3,3,3)
end

script.Parent.MouseButton1Up:Connect(Click)
```

You can scale the meshes not the Humanoid Values

Comment: Ok but I want to make a game that I want it when you press a TextButton(Gui) It makes you bigger and this is the most I need. Can you help? (I am a new scripter and I dont know too much)